# Mediawiki 1.39.3 update. Main slot of revision not found in database. See T212428

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-installation

I have just migrated Mediawiki from 1.33.0 to 1.39.3 and I got this error:

```
Original exception: [9e4b6c3104e4e770f4b2a2bb] /index.php/Accueil MediaWiki\Revision\RevisionAccessException: Main slot of revision not found in database. See T212428.
Backtrace:
from D:\wamp64.3.3.0\www\mediawiki-1.39.3\includes\Revision\RevisionStore.php(1518)
#0 D:\wamp64.3.3.0\www\mediawiki-1.39.3\includes\Revision\RevisionStore.php(1377): MediaWiki\Revision\RevisionStore->constructSlotRecords(integer, array, integer, Title)
#1 D:\wamp64.3.3.0\www\mediawiki-1.39.3\includes\Revision\RevisionStore.php(1554): MediaWiki\Revision\RevisionStore->loadSlotRecords(integer, integer, Title)
#2 [internal function]: MediaWiki\Revision\RevisionStore->MediaWiki\Revision\{closure}()
#3 D:\wamp64.3.3.0\www\mediawiki-1.39.3\includes\Revision\RevisionSlots.php(170): call_user_func(Closure)
#4 D:\wamp64.3.3.0\www\mediawiki-1.39.3\includes\Revision\RevisionSlots.php(109): MediaWiki\Revision\RevisionSlots->getSlots()
#5 D:\wamp64.3.3.0\www\mediawiki-1.39.3\includes\Revision\RevisionRecord.php(181): MediaWiki\Revision\RevisionSlots->getSlot(string)
#6 D:\wamp64.3.3.0\www\mediawiki-1.39.3\includes\page\WikiPage.php(673): MediaWiki\Revision\RevisionRecord->getSlot(string, integer)
#7 D:\wamp64.3.3.0\www\mediawiki-1.39.3\includes\libs\objectcache\wancache\WANObjectCache.php(1689): WikiPage->{closure}(boolean, integer, array, NULL, array)
#8 D:\wamp64.3.3.0\www\mediawiki-1.39.3\includes\libs\objectcache\wancache\WANObjectCache.php(1522): WANObjectCache->fetchOrRegenerate(string, integer, Closure, array, array)
#9 D:\wamp64.3.3.0\www\mediawiki-1.39.3\includes\page\WikiPage.php(687): WANObjectCache->getWithSetCallback(string, integer, Closure, array)
#10 D:\wamp64.3.3.0\www\mediawiki-1.39.3\includes\page\WikiPage.php(296): WikiPage->getContentModel()
#11 D:\wamp64.3.3.0\www\mediawiki-1.39.3\includes\MediaWiki.php(437): WikiPage->getContentHandler()
#12 D:\wamp64.3.3.0\www\mediawiki-1.39.3\includes\MediaWiki.php(320): MediaWiki->initializeArticle()
#13 D:\wamp64.3.3.0\www\mediawiki-1.39.3\includes\MediaWiki.php(904): MediaWiki->performRequest()
#14 D:\wamp64.3.3.0\www\mediawiki-1.39.3\includes\MediaWiki.php(562): MediaWiki->main()
#15 D:\wamp64.3.3.0\www\mediawiki-1.39.3\index.php(50): MediaWiki->run()
#16 D:\wamp64.3.3.0\www\mediawiki-1.39.3\index.php(46): wfIndexMain()
#17 {main}
```

Can anybody help?

All resources found are for older versions of Mediawiki. Anybody has a solution for 1.39.3 ?

Comment: Try incremental upgrade: first upgrade to 1.35, then run `update.php`, then upgrade to `1.39`, then run update.php again.